# Http Get a plist in XML format to an array or to file, then to an array?

Tags: iphone, xml, nsarray, plist, http-get

I'm replacing a simple initWithContentsOfURL: with a dynamic HttpGet where I pass two parameters and that webpage returns the exact same data as XML in text format.

Must I really parse the data to get it into an array of dictionaries? I was hoping for NSXMLParser initWithData: and then some automated way of initalizing an NSArray with all nodes, structure following the XML. (It is a plist in XML format, so the structure and all key names are already in it. Why should I have to write a replica of all that in Objective-C as well?!)

I'd be happy with httpgetting to a text file and then NSArray initWithContentsOfFile.

Edit: This yields an NSData object 26K in size, but the error message "Conversion of the string failed. The string is empty".

```
//Initiate connection
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease]; [request setURL:url(aspurl)];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    //keep adding your headers this way
NSString *accept = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,/*;q=0.5"];
[request addValue:accept forHTTPHeaderField: @"Accept"];
    //send request & get response
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSString *errString;
NSMutableArray *arr=[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:returnData
                                         mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainers
                                                   format: NULL 
                             errorDescription:&errString];

if (errString)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",errString);
    [errString release]; // exception to the rules
}
```

This gives the error "Conversion of string failed. The string is empty." and arr is 0x0.

Can anyone point out my mistake?

Comment: if you need easy parsing which results in dictionaries and arrays and you are able to make changes on the API use JSON with the json-framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First-off, you could use a class like [XML-to-NSDictionary](https://github.com/bcaccinolo/XML-to-NSDictionary) to do the parsing, and it could be dead simple, but it seems you don't like that approach.

Since you are dealing with a plist, as an alternative, you can:

1. use `NSURLConnection` to load the plist into an `NSData`;
2. use `[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:mutabilityOption:format:errorDescription:method]` to convert that into an `NSDictionary/NSArray`;

Have also a look at [Property List Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Thanks. Tried #2. Can you spot the error in my edited original post?

Comment: @Henrik: Your code seems ok to me; the only thing could be with the data. I would try and convert the NSData to NSString and inspect its content: `NSString *content = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];`

Comment: Paste same url in Safari, source->XML validator, no errors found. Usually if there is an error with initWithContentsofURL (I've done it many times with plist-xml _files_), you get an empty object, but it worked with the same data in this app. Perhaps not same behavior for NSURLRequest, but content with your code is (null) if that's a lead.

Comment: Can you try `initWithData` specifying `NSASCIIStringEncoding` as encoding? Sorry for yet another try, but if we cannot get the XML out of the NSData in a readable way, then here is the problem...

Comment: Just did that exactly 13 seconds ago :D It's a classic. I assumed I got the same encoding as in the file coming from the same script, which was UTF-8. Script guy will get an earache on Monday morning... ;) Can I temporarily serialize string to file and file to NSArray?

Comment: Strange, all I needed to do was write the "ascii" string to file and do {NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData}, and the property list was perfect, with UTF-8 nonascii characters like å showing correctly. Correct answer marked and +1 for the extra help :) Have a good weekend!